# Maximum number of interfaces in linux

Tags: interface, kernel, vpn, ethernet

What is the max/recommended maximum of number of interfaces I can have with linux kernel 5?

I'am planing to have a host(s) that will terminate thousands of VPN networks, each will create a separate ethernet interface. So I need to know how many Linux machines I will need to implement to handle all my VPN networks.

I have tryed to create 20 VPN "virtual" ethernet interfaces, but would like to know what's the maximum alowed number of interfaces I can create. Information varies greately 32 to 4089 to even 8192...